# How to integrate elasticsearch with rails application specifically using "Elasticsearch" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, rubygems

I am new to rails and to elastic search. I have seen other resources to configure using Tire, Searchkick and some others, but I want to use `Elasticsearch` gem. I have running rails application and running Elasticsearch server on my system but I do not how to configure them to communicate with each other.

Currently, I am facing a lot of troubles to do the same. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your elasticsearch related code, and we don't know what's your problem/error.

Comment: require "elasticsearch/model"

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Elasticsearch::Model
 include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
 has_many :requests, :class_name => "::Request"
 belongs_to :employee, :class_name => "::Employee"
end

Service.import

Comment: Error ActionView::Template::Error ([404] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_fo
und_exception","reason":"no such index","index":"services","resource.type":"inde
x_or_alias","resource.id":"services"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reaso
n":"no such index","index":"services","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource
.id":"services"},"status":404}):

Comment: class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_service, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /services
  # GET /services.json
  def index
    @services = Service.search((params[:q].present? ? params[:q] : "*")).records
  end
end

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a very basic quick start of the elastic's github gem for model indexing you could do the following in development environment with elasticsearch running on localhost:9200

in Gemfile:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
```

then run on terminal:

```
$ bundle install
```

in app/models/service.rb include right after class declaration:

```
include Elasticsearch::Model
```

you can now play with it on console with existing data (results are just an example):

```
$ rails console

# Create the index for Service model on elasticsearch
> Service.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
=> {"acknowledged"=>true}

# Import current Service records into the index
> Service.import
  Service Load (207.3ms)  SELECT  "services".* FROM "services"  ORDER BY "services"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000

# Sample search returning total results
> Service.__elasticsearch__.search("mykeyword").results.total
=> 123
```

For more information and details you can take a look at the project's [github page](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)

Answer (score 1):

Better use [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails)

in Gemfile:

```
gem install elasticsearch-rails
```

To import the records from your Article model, run:

```
$ bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Article'
```

To limit the imported records to a certain ActiveRecord scope, pass it to the task:

```
$ bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Article' SCOPE='published'
```

Run this command to display usage instructions:

```
$ bundle exec rake -D elasticsearch
```

If you want to use for model

[elasticsearch-model](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model), which contains search integration for Ruby/Rails models such as ActiveRecord::Base and Mongoid,

Comment: Does not "Elasticsearch" do the samething as done by both Elasticsearch-rails and Elasticsearch-model, I read Elasticsearch-rails in companion to Elasticsearch-rails so I thought instead of using two gems it is better to use one i.e Elasticsearch..please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I built an application. Now, I wanna add a feature so that user can refine the search based on selection like done by flipkart, paytm on different product.

Comment: yes right for your rails app use elastic-rails The elasticsearch-rails library is a companion for the the elasticsearch-model library, providing features suitable for Ruby on Rails applications.

Comment: I have added Elasticsearch-rails, Elasticsearch-model in gem file...Elasticsearch server is running at port no. 9200. but it through following error. My model name is "Service" services does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it.

Comment: C:\datacheck> bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='SER
VICE'
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: services does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or
 the :force option to create it.
C:in `import'
C:/datacheck/app/models/service.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
(eval):1:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => elasticsearch:import:model
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

When I ran  bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Service'

Comment: @Rahul I had the same issue mentioned in the comment above and just ran `Service.__elasticsearch__.create_index!` within the rails console and then the `Service.import` worked just fine. Hope it helps!