# Bonsai: Use create_index! or the :force option to create it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

For the past 4 weeks I've been fighting a loosing battle with Bonsai and Elasticsearch, which in someways is disheartening because a few months ago I had it working on another app.
My app is crashed, when I go to Heroku I just get the "Application Error" warning.  When I checkout the `Herkou Logs` I find something that I believe to be the problem:

```
2016-08-31T23:23:47.189996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-01T00:12:50.088164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-01T00:12:57.130922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 14657 -e production`
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947244+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947263+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:14657
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947264+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947265+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947266+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947281+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.9/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:118:in `import': professors does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it. (ArgumentError)
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947282+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.9/lib/elasticsearch/model.rb:116:in `import'
2016-09-01T00:13:00.947283+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/professor.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
```

Specifically this line:

```
 import': professors does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it. (ArgumentError)
```

Everything works fine on Localhost but it crashes with Heroku.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867852/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-with-rails-application-specifically-using-elasti) which I think is similar to mine and one of the answers said to try:

```
    $ rails console

# Create the index for Service model on elasticsearch
> Service.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
=> {"acknowledged"=>true}

# Import current Service records into the index
> Service.import
  Service Load (207.3ms)  SELECT  "services".* FROM "services"  ORDER BY "services"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000

# Sample search returning total results
> Service.__elasticsearch__.search("mykeyword").results.total
=> 123
```

But whenever I run a rails console in Heroku `heroku run rails console`  I get pretty much the same error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.9/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:118:in `import': professors does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it. (ArgumentError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-0.1.9/lib/elasticsearch/model.rb:116:in `import'
```

Comment: man! Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945378/rake-environment-elastic-searchimportall-force-y-keeps-failing/42515534#42515534), it might help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

Just use `Service.import(force: true)` to import data.

If index already exists, it will delete index and re-create it before import data.

If index not exists, it will create index and import data directly.

so no need `Service.__elasticsearch__.create_index!` anymore.